# Using telnet to communicate with QNX Neutrino via TCP/IP in C++

Tags: c++, tcp, client, telnet, qnx-neutrino

I'm able to access a telnet server via PuTTY which opens a terminal and allows me to send commands to retrieve data/logs and start/stop processes.  I'd like to begin some research into how to access this server via C++ in order to automate the connection and the commands for testing.  Basically I need a telnet client that can connect and authenticate itself, and write and read to/from the server as if I'm typing in a terminal.  Where should I start my research? I've tried a couple examples including:

http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/att-40895/telnet.cpp

When I compile and run

```
./telnet 192.168.1.26 23
```

Nothing happens, but when I connect to the server with PuTTY I get:

```
QNX Neutrino (localhost) (ttyp0)

login: root  
password:  
#
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Notes:
- I am using a Mac running OS X Version 10.7.3 with i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2
- I am allowed to be doing this.
- I use PuTTY on my Windows 7 machine, the connection is ethernet to USB ethernet adapter, and the settings for the Local Area Connection Properties > TCP/IPv4 Properties: are a specific IP address, Subnet Mask, and Default gateway, which might be useful information.

Thanks

Comment: What about starting with putty? Its source is available...

Comment: *"the connection is ethernet to USB ethernet adapter, and the settings for the Local Area Connection Properties > TCP/IPv4 Properties: are a specific IP address, Subnet Mask, and Default gateway, which might be useful information"* Your OS should (in fact *does*) shield the application from all of this junk.

Comment: Why: you can use ssh to authenticate and run commands: ssh <host> <command>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Learn how to program TCP/IP sockets.  You can use the boost libraries, or straight C style BSD sockets.  Some info [here](http://www.cis.temple.edu/~giorgio/old/cis307s96/readings/docs/sockets.html), [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=bsd%20sockets&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CG8QFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets&ei=uyKoT4LBFtSgiQfQnLGmAw&usg=AFQjCNE6liNHEFW3sMjc15OHRpgG_lm8Rg&cad=rja) and [here](http://www.cs.vu.nl/~jms/socket-info.html).  If paper is your thing, you could get Volume 1 of [Unix Network Programming](http://www.unpbook.com/).  That book has such a good reputation that you get votes just for *mentioning* it on StackOverflow.
2. What you want to do closely matches the functionality of `telnet` and `expect`.  You can have a look at there sources [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/inetutils/) and [here](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) for ideas.
3. Consider just using `expect` to solve your problem :)

Comment: +1 not only, but in the first place for mentioning Stevens'  "Unix Network Programming"  :-).

Comment: and no one mentioned boost::asio .. shame

Answer (score 1):

You should start by learning the network API for the system you're trying to connect from.  Telnet is just sending straight up text through a tcp/ip socket.